# Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'. Overload 2 of 3, '(nam

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I was trying to upload a file an image to cloudniary when i was doing the same thing in js it was working fine but when i re wrtie all my codebase in tsx it shows a red line error on my vs code on line `data.append('file', { uri: image.path, type: 'image/jpeg', name: 'image.jpg' });`  Can anyone please tell me how can i fix this problem with my code?

Error:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 3, '(name: string, value: string | Blob): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ uri: string; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to  parameter of type 'string | Blob'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'.
  Overload 2 of 3, '(name: string, value: string): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ uri: string; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 3 of 3, '(name: string, blobValue: Blob, filename?: string): void', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ uri: string; type: string; name: string; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Blob'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'uri' does not exist in type 'Blob'.
```

```
const SelectImage = async (): Promise<{ path: string; url: string } | null> => {
    try {
        const image = await ImagePicker.openPicker({
            mediaType: 'photo',
            cropping: true,
            cropperCircleOverlay: true,
            cropperActiveWidgetColor: '#ffffff',
            cropperStatusBarColor: '#000000',
            cropperToolbarColor: '#000000',
            cropperToolbarTitle: 'Crop your image',
            cropperToolbarWidgetColor: '#ffffff',
            compressImageQuality: 1,
            compressVideoPreset: 'MediumQuality',
            compressVideoBitrate: 500000,
            compressVideoResolution: '720p',
            width: 300,
            height: 300,
            mime: 'image/jpeg',
            multiple: false,
        });

        console.log(image.path);
        const cloudName = 'cloudname';
        const unsignedUploadPreset = 'preset';
        const url = `https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/${cloudName}/upload`;

        const data = new FormData();
        data.append('file', { uri: image.path, type: 'image/jpeg', name: 'image.jpg' });
        data.append('upload_preset', unsignedUploadPreset);

        const response = await fetch(url, {
            method: 'POST', 
            body: data,
        });
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result.secure_url);
        return { path: image.path, url: result.secure_url };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        return null;
    }
};
```

Comment: The error seems pretty clear. It's saying there are three overloads for `data.append` and that your call doesn't match any of them. Looking at the overloads listed, indeed, there's no match. Only two overloads take two parameters, and the second parameter must be either a `string` or `Blob` but you're passing an object. So...?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder can you please tell me how can I fix this? i am new to typescript

Comment: Is it common to get these errors typescript?

Comment: You fix it by not trying to pass an invalid value to `data.append` -- instead, pass a string or a Blob. Other than that, I've never used cloudniary, so I can't help you with how to fix it. And yes, the whole point of TypeScript is to point out programming errors like this.